# Overload Resolution: Templatized member function vs friend function for stream operator

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, gcc, operator-overloading

Suppose we have this scenario(maybe a little bit artificial)

```
class OStream
{
   virtual void f1() = 0;
    ...
   virtual void f10() = 0;
 
   template<typename T>
   OStream& operator<<(const T& t)
   {
     //doing something
   }
};

class MyClass : public OStream
{
   virtual void f1() override;
   ...
   virtual void f10() override;
}
```

In another CPP file, there is another Foo class defined with a friend function like this

```
friend OStream& operator<<(OStream& ostream, Foo& obj)
{
  //doing something with obj
}
```

Now consider a completely different file that contains such a snippet

```
...
MyClass obj; //suppose the constructor is defined 
Foo foo; //there as well
obj << foo; // which operator is called???? I guess the second one
...
```

And what operator will be called if I overload `OStream::operator<<` inside `MyClass`(it is templated(thus non-virtual), thus I am just hiding the original one?

Comment: *"And what operator will be called if I overload OStream::operator<< inside MyClass(it is templated(thus non-virtual), thus I am just hiding the original one?"* - Show that in code, not prose. The answer posted bellow seems to have missed that.

Comment: The code doesn't even compile. `const T& T` is not allowed. Please show an actual [mre].

Comment: If both operators are visible and viable at the point of call, overload resolution is performed. Overload resolution prefers a non-template over a template, other things equal.